# How to close Outlook program gracefully without use's interact to backup PST files?

Tags: powershell, outlook

I need some help on this code, i use it into a batch file all day @ 3 AM.
The goal is to close Outlook properly to make backup of Outlook PST file.

In a specific context, if some panel are opened like **account parameter panel from Outlook**, it cannot be able to do the action and the script is looping.
As i execute powershell script from a batch (.bat) like this **start /wait PowerShell -NoLogo -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%~dp0CloseOutlook.ps1'"**, the powershell script continues to work silently if i close my batch (powershell process continu to run with infinite loop).
In this case, if i go to other applications, he tries to make hotkey (ALT+Y), which could be dangerous.

Is there any way to modify Powershell script to do hotkey (ALT+Y) only in the Outlook application to prevent the script from interacting with other applications?
In order to avoid infinite loops in the background, can we also tell him to do 50 x ALT + Y to exit powershell script ?
This will avoid having a process that runs in a loop.

```
$isOutlookOpen = Get-Process outlook*
if($isOutlookOpen = $null){
    # Outlook is already closed run code here:
    }
else {
     $isOutlookOpen = Get-Process outlook*

     # while loop makes sure all outlook windows are closed before moving on to other code:
         while($isOutlookOpen -ne $null){
            Get-Process outlook* | ForEach-Object {$_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null }
            sleep 5
            If(($isOutlookOpen = Get-Process outlook*) -ne $null){
            Write-Host "Outlook is Open.......Closing Outlook"
                $wshell = new-object -com wscript.shell
                $wshell.AppActivate("Microsoft Outlook")
                $wshell.Sendkeys("%(Y)")
            $isOutlookOpen = Get-Process outlook*
            }
        }
        #Outlook has been closed run code here:
    }
```

If you know a better way to improve this code to close Outlook properly, please advise :)

Just to be more precise, i don't want to make Shadow copy with Hobocopy, or Shadowspawn (new name), these tools are not able to handle quote with robocopy command, so there is no way possible to use it if you have space in paths... too bad !
Anyway, backing up Outlook pst files when Outlook is still open, regardless of program being used, is an invitation for problems (to play Russian roulette)

So it seems more secure to try to close Outlook to backup pst file as well.

Many thanks for all.

Comment: Just for information, you're not running a powershell command you're running a file. `Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -File "%~dp0CloseOutlook.ps1"`

Comment: I am pretty sure you don't like to hear that and this discussion does not belong here but the question is not how to it. The actual question is "Should you do it at all?". And the answer is definitely "No". In an enterprise environment, and I hope we're talking about something like this, you should offer enough mailbox space on the server. Or even offer a reasonable archive policy with archive mailboxes on the server. "Managing" local PST files is just the wrong way.